# Android setText() Different Layout File

Tags: android

I'm trying to use setText to show different text within the same layout everytime someone clicks a different picture.
So all the layout files stay the same the only thing that needs to change is the android:text in that layout.

I've created a class with case statement for when someone presses on a picture and then call setText().

But it looks like the setText isn't even called. because I can see my Log.v that is called within the same case statement but the text doesn't change.

PictureInfo.java

```
public class PictureInfo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        private static final String TAG = "Popup";

        public TextView infoText;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            final LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            infoText = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.information, null);



            View a1Button = findViewById(R.id.a1);
            a1Button.setOnClickListener(this);



        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
            {
                switch(v.getId())
                {

                    case R.id.a1:

                    Intent a = new Intent(this, Information.class);
                    startActivity(a);
                    Log.v(TAG, "Change setText");
                    infoText.setText(R.string.a2_text);
                    break;
                }

            }

    }
```

information.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <TextView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/information_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/a1_text"
      />
```

Comment: You are opening an `Activity` before changing the text,so you are unable to see the changed text.

Comment: @dave.c no my Information.java calls information.xml and my PictureInfo.java calls main.xml. that's why I created the inflate to load information.xml when the setContentView of main.xml is called) so that way I should be able to edit the xml of information.xml even though I don't actually load it as layout

Comment: @Tanmay Mandal, this doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are inflating a `layout` - `R.layout.information`, but casting this to a `TextView`.  I'm really not sure what you are doing there.

I **think** you want the destination `Activity` to use some text in its layout that the source `Activity` provides to it.  Why not pass the `id` of the text you want displayed as an `Extra` on the `Intent`?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.a1:
        Intent a = new Intent(this, Information.class);
        intent.putExtra("com.packagename.identifier", R.string.a2_text);
        startActivity(a);
        break;
    }
}
```

Then in your Information Activity:

```
public class Information extends Activity {
    ...
    TextView myTextView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextViewId);
        ...
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            int textId = extras.getInt("com.packagename.identifier");
            infoText.setText(textId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought I could add another layout file with inflate so I could use the other layout files ids even thought that layout file is not loaded with setContentView(). I got your solution working now! what you did is put the string value of a2_text in an intent that will be pushed to the information.class and then pull out that string in the information.class?   I'm rather new to this and just trying to understand it all ;). Thanks for your fast and spot on answer!

Comment: Exactly.  Your other approach might work too, but I find this route means that each `Activity` is updating it's own layout, and is therefore easier to work with.

Comment: Yes, I think it will be easy to maintain with different classes. my point of view was just that I got several images with different information to be shown in the same layout and this does the trick and I can now do this by every case statement and just change the R.string

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the code to:

```
 //First change text
 Log.v(TAG, "Change setText");
 infoText.setText(R.string.a2_text);

 //Then call new activity
 Intent a = new Intent(this, Information.class);
 startActivity(a);
```

And voilá!

Comment: Probably the time between changing the text and the new activity being launched is too small. If you remove the startActivity the text changes? If it does.. you need to introduce a time between changing it and going to the next activity.